# Highcharts Heatmap Edit Legend

Tags: json, highcharts, heatmap

How can I edit the text of my Legend in my Heatmap?
http://jsfiddle.net/z3auc57d/4/

I would like to edit the Text "0, 2.5 ...10" to say "Low" and "High" for the left and rightmost text resp.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            credits: false,
                title: false,
        legend: {},
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            data: data
        }],
        legend:{
        //...
        },
         colorAxis: {
            minColor: '#A3D9FF',
            maxColor: '#FF5460'
        }
    });
```

Could find anything appropriate in the API doc yet...
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.heatmap.showInLegend

Comment: You can use colorAxis.labels.formatter function. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/z3auc57d/5/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ioying/aey0coov/

```
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.isFirst) {
        return 'low ' +this.value;
      } else if (this.isLast) {
            return '  '+ this.value + 'high ';
      } else {
          return this.value;
      }
    }
  }
```